# Stackoverflow times out when posting data

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, user-interface

Multiple times now, within the past 30 mins (2:15pm-2:45pm PST 7/17/09) I notice that stack overflow times out when I try to post something. This has happened on 3 occasions now.

1. Editing a question I have and clicking save
2. Editing my user profile information and clicking save
3. Trying to answer a question and posting my answer

The first instance of this happening the request timed out and my post didnt get saved. The ohter 2 times the request timed out but still saved my what I was posting.

Answer (score 1):

We have sporadic reports of this, but can never reproduce it.

We suspect networking.

Where on the planet Earth are you? what country, etc?

Comment: San Diego, CA, USA

Comment: It happens to me too from time to time. Both when posting comments and answers. Firefox, winxp, Sweden.

Comment: I get it very rarely but generally attribute it to my saturated office network; Firefox, Win7, Ohio

Comment: I have this problem too on occasion.  (Zurich)  It happens disproportionately more with with SO than the other sites I visit frequently.  The problem even seems to occur with voting.

Answer (score 0):

Getting this same problem, everytime I edit one of my posts, it takes ages, and I can't access any of the stackoverflow sites (including meta) during this time.  By design? some sort of throttling? or is it network issue?

Comment: sounds like a network issue to me